# Broken Ubuntu repo, Depends: xxx but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

My Ubuntu 18.04 repo is broken with the "`Depends: xxx but it is not going to be installed`" error. Further investigation makes me believe it is caused by the conflict naming convention of the package versions:

```
% apt install libqt5gui5
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0 (>= 0.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


% apt install libxkbcommon-x11-0
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxkbcommon-x11-0 : Depends: libxkbcommon0 (= 0.8.0-1) but 0.8.0-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


% apt-cache policy libxkbcommon0
libxkbcommon0:
  Installed: 0.8.0-1ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 0.8.0-1ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.8.0-1ubuntu0.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.8.0-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

I.e., the `libxkbcommon0` was `0.8.0-1ubuntu0.1` when I first installed it, but it is now of version `0.8.0-1` (same version but without the `ubuntu0.1`), which is causing  the trouble all the way up to the "`Depends: xxx but it is not going to be installed`" error.

How to fix it?

PS. my system:

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

$ uname -rm 
4.15.0-20-generic x86_64
```

I.e., I don't have other non-x86 architectures in my sources.

Comment: Can you please confirm your architecture.  I note an amd64 in your `apt-cache policy`, and the version a rule mentions (no "ubuntu0.1") applies to arm64/armh/ppc... (not amd64/i386) - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libxkbcommon-x11  Do you have other non-x86 architectures in your sources?

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, OP updated.

Comment: `0.8.0-1ubuntu0.1` is provided by -security and -updates, while `0.8.0-1` is in the base repo. Since the -security and -updates repos did not show up in your output, look into /etc/apt/sources.list. Ensure you have the 'bionic-security' and 'bionic-updated' repositories enabled. Then run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: I still have `0.8.0-1ubuntu0.1` which makes me think you have incorporated a ppa or something that your system is trying to pull this other version from. What exactly are you trying to do, and what changes to software sources have you make from the basic configuration?

Comment: Thanks @user535733, that's exactly the reason and the solution.